# Azure static web site count unique clients

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am hosting Azure static web site using Azure Storage, CDN Profile and End Point. I want to see the outgoing traffic. Currently I can only see that for the storage account but I can't see where I can actually count unique site visitors. Please, help. I am OK if it can only be done through powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature available to get the user visits count, However there are two ways to achieve that:

[**By Enabling Application Insights**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript): Once you enable you will be able to view the user device,name,count etc

[**View Storage Analytics Logs:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics) This is like a backend view, You can view the storage analytics logs to view the operations performed on blobs